# How to create dynamic model in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to create a dynamic ember data models.I have tried this code in `route\user` like:

```
var tableColumns = {
   name: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string')
};
let store = this.get('store');
Ember.getOwner(store).register('model: user', DS.Model.extend(tableColumns));
```

after creating a model for `this.store.findAll(user)`.
but it's not working and it shows model `user` is not defined.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this? Dynamically generating models is mostly not a good idea. Oh, and the space in `model: user` is wrong.

Comment: I suggest using plain objects with custom service in this case. Dynamic models is not a right approach for ember.js afaik.